# Content Security Policy directive "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'"

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

I'm attempting to write a Chrome extension to return weather observations from the nearest station using ipinfo.io and the mesowest.utah.edu API services. The desired output from the extension are current air temperature and wind speed observations from the nearest weather station, using IP address geolocation.

I am presented CSP protocol errors in a send request executed by jQuery, after inspecting the popup of the extension. The script that executes this request is my JavaScript employing the .get() method to obtain observations from an API service (api.mesowest.net).

A working fiddle of the raw HTML and JavaScript can be seen at [http://jsfiddle.net/zK5FN/3467/][1], but do not produce errors as they do when packaged and ran as a Chrome extension:

My manifest.json is:

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Sensible Weather",
"description": "This extension will return simple weather obs for a site",
"version": "2.1",

"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "day16.png",
  "default_popup": "popup.html",
  "default_title": "Weather at your location"
 },

 "icons": { "16": "day16.png",
            "48": "day48.png",
            "128": "day128.png"
          },

 "content_scripts": [
     {
         "matches": ["https://*.ipinfo.io/", "https://*.api.mesowest.net/"],
         "js": ["jquery-3.3.1.min.js", "./popupObs.js"]
     }
 ],

 "content_security_policy": "script-src https://ipinfo.io/json/ https://*.api.mesowest.net/ https://synopticlabs.org/api/mesonet/ https://*.github.com/ https://rawgit.com/fairlycasual/willChromeExtension.github.io/master/popupObsAsync.js 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src https://*.api.mesowest.net/ https://ipinfo.io/json/ https://*rawgit.com/ 'unsafe-inline'; object-src https://ipinfo.io/json/ https://*.api.mesowest.net/",

 "permissions": [
   "activeTab",
   "https://*.api.mesowest.net/"
  ]
}
```

My JavaScript:

```
async function getObs() {
  var info = await fetch(`https://ipinfo.io/json/`)
    .then(resp => resp.json());
  var obs = await fetch(`https://api.mesowest.net/v2/stations/nearesttime?&radius=${info.loc},100&limit=1&units=ENGLISH&token=804c1eb09a394255beef8e84b68123bf&vars=air_temp,wind_speed/`)
  .then(resp => resp.json());
  console.log(obs);
  var tempOut;
  var windOut;
  var stnName = obs.STATION[0].NAME;
  var stnDist = obs.STATION[0].DISTANCE;
  console.log(stnName);
  console.log(stnDist);
  // Populate variables with obs to display
  if (obs.STATION[0].OBSERVATIONS.air_temp_value_1 !== undefined) {
          tempOut = obs.STATION[0].OBSERVATIONS.air_temp_value_1.value;
        } else {tempOut = 'temp undefined';}
        console.log(tempOut);

  if (obs.STATION[0].OBSERVATIONS.wind_speed_value_1 !== undefined) {
          windOut = obs.STATION[0].OBSERVATIONS.wind_speed_value_1.value + ' MPH';
        } else {windOut = 'no wind data at site';}
        console.log(windOut);

  var outArr = ['Air temperature is ' +tempOut+' degrees F, wind speed: ' + windOut + '. Observations from the ' + stnName + ' site located ' + stnDist + ' miles from you.'];
  console.log(outArr);
  document.getElementById('obs').innerHTML=outArr;
  }

getObs()
```

And my HTML:

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="style-src 'unsafe-inline'; script-src https://*.api.mesowest.org/ https://ipinfo.io/json/ https://*.github.com/ https://rawgit.com/fairlycasual/willChromeExtension.github.io/master/popupObsAsync.js 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; connect-src https://*.api.mesowest.net/ https://ipinfo.io/json/ https://rawgit.com/fairlycasual/willChromeExtension.github.io/master/popupObsAsync.js https://*.github.com/ 'unsafe-inline';">
    <script src="../jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javscript" src="https://ipinfo.io/json/"></script>
    <h3>Nearest weather observations by IP geolocation using <a href="http://ipinfo.io">ipinfo.io</a></h3>
  </head>
  <body>
   <div id="mesowest">
     <p id="obs">Observations courtesy of the MesoWest API service.

     </p>
   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/fairlycasual/willChromeExtension.github.io/master/popupObsAsync.js"> </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

And the errors I receive are:

```
popupObsAsync.js:4 Refused to connect to 'https://api.mesowest.net/v2/stations/nearesttime?&radius=47.9790,-122.2020,100&limit=1&units=ENGLISH&token=804c1eb09a394255beef8e84b68123bf&vars=air_temp,wind_speed' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src https://*.api.mesowest.net/ https://ipinfo.io/json/ https://*rawgit.com/ 'unsafe-inline'".

getObs @ popupObsAsync.js:4
popupObsAsync.js:4 Refused to connect to 'https://api.mesowest.net/v2/stations/nearesttime?&radius=47.9790,-122.2020,100&limit=1&units=ENGLISH&token=804c1eb09a394255beef8e84b68123bf&vars=air_temp,wind_speed' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "connect-src https://*.api.mesowest.net/ https://ipinfo.io/json/ https://rawgit.com/fairlycasual/willChromeExtension.github.io/master/popupObsAsync.js https://*.github.com/ 'unsafe-inline'".

    getObs @ popupObsAsync.js:4
    popupObsAsync.js:4 Refused to connect to 'https://api.mesowest.net/v2/stations/nearesttime?&radius=47.9790,-122.2020,100&limit=1&units=ENGLISH&token=804c1eb09a394255beef8e84b68123bf&vars=air_temp,wind_speed' because it violates the document's Content Security Policy.
    getObs @ popupObsAsync.js:4
    popupObsAsync.js:4 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
        at getObs (popupObsAsync.js:4)
        at <anonymous>
```

I have waded through many different errors, eventually getting so that only one was returned with the API call, although it works well in other compilers. Now it is throwing me four errors from the same line.

Comment: Update: 
I have gotten it down to the point where the only CSP error I receive is from the API call to obtain observations. Initially, the geolocation call is executed correctly, and inserted into the get request to the mesowest API, but I receive the Refused to Load Script error again. At this point I do not have any directives in the script-src command,but it still fails. Any insight?

Comment: Edited question to adhere to a clear problem statement, and requisite code layout. Please un-hold if it conforms. Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to use JSONP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use JSONP.

```
async function getObs() {
    const info = await fetch(`https://ipinfo.io/json`)
      .then(resp => resp.json());
    const obs = await fetch(`http://api.mesowest.net/v2/stations/nearesttime?&radius=${info.loc},100&limit=1&units=ENGLISH&token=804c1eb09a394255beef8e84b68123bf&vars=air_temp,wind_speed`)
      .then(resp => resp.json());
    console.log(obs);
}
```

But if you do want to keep your CSP, it's most likely that you're setting allow-origin **https**://api.mesowest.net but your code is calling **http**://api.mesowest.net, as the error indicates. (And even if you tried to allow **http**, Chrome would disallow this in an extension.)

Comment: I have come to understand that the problem I am facing is due to my approach, you cannot serve https over jQuery http get requests. I'm attempting to find a work around, or the proper implementation of the async await method. Thanks again.

Comment: Successfully reconfigured my popupObs.js script to the async version you suggested @JoshLee, now going through the debugging of MIME types again for ipinfo.io etc... We will see how it goes!
https://jsfiddle.net/bjscrgqz/27/